# Making a function that creates a button HTML/JS

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a function which takes a characters and makes a button with the character inside it. Here's what I have so far:

```
function keyButton(char) {
  var btn = document.createElement("button"); //create button
  btn.innerText = char; //fill it with char
  return btn;
    }

  var button = keyButton("a"); //use keyButton to fill buttons with characters
  document.appendChild(button);
```

This however doesn't seem to work, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Appending the button to `document` is probably the issue. Try `document.body.appendChild(button);` maybe.

Comment: How does it not work?

Comment: Also make sure you're keeping the developer console open so that you can see any reported errors.

Comment: `document.body.appendChild(button);` works fine, I was just not calling the script in the body. Thanks!

Comment: Does your dev console show any error? Can you please copy paste or show the errors shown in the console?

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use [`document.createTextNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTextNode) for making a text node and append the button to [`document.body`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/body).

```js
function keyButton(char) {
    var btn = document.createElement("button");
    btn.appendChild(document.createTextNode(char));
    return btn;
}

var button = keyButton("a");
document.body.appendChild(button);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's exactly as @Pointy said, you can't append the button to the document. If you try this out in the console, you should get this error:
[image: screenshot]

If you change `document.appendChild(button);` to `document.body.appendChild(button);` it will work:[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use body to append child in dom

```
document.body.appendChild();
```

if you do `console.log(btn);` it returns button with char which you have passed in function that means your code is correct.Your only mistake is you have forgottend `body` with `document`
Here is working code

```
function keyButton(char) {
  var btn = document.createElement("button"); //create button
  btn.innerText = char; //fill it with char
  return btn;
    }

  var button = keyButton("a"); //use keyButton to fill buttons with characters
console.log(button);
 document.body.appendChild(button);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not insert a `button` to the `document`, if you do that, you will get `HierarchyRequestError: Node cannot be inserted at the specified point in the hierarchy` (At least in Firefox), so you have to add it to a visible element in your page, such as `document.body`.